# PHPExcel Crash with getCalculatedValue

Tags: php, mysql, excel, phpexcel

I've been using PHPExcel for about a year to import data from spreadsheets in random cells. The code looks like this:

```
$value1 = test_input($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B13')->getCalculatedValue());
```

Recently, I changed the Excel sheets to run a more complex formula. The basic premise is that the sheet pulls data from a mySQL DB, which in turn is used in vlookups based on a dropdown to populate several fields. All relevant fields across the workbook are referenced on a final sheet for importing into the DB.

The problem now is that PHPExcel is crashing (diagnosing in NetBeans) when it comes to the cells with these calculated formulas. It works fine with most formulas, but when referencing cells which reference the cells with if > vlookup > ODBC link to mySQL, it crashes the program and stops the file import. Should I be using a different function, or what is causing it not to return the value?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: If the worksheet itself is pulling in data from a remote ODBC link, then PHPExcel can't replicate that functionality

Comment: The data pulled in is stored on a hidden worksheet, but is locally copied for the vlookups. Would this be an issue still, perhaps too many iterations for PHPExcel to follow? When I step through the code, it seems to keep going back and forth between the calculation page and another page. Thanks @MarkBaker !

Comment: I modified the worksheet, and it is now using VBA to set the cell value in the parent worksheet. PHPExcel is now pulling a simple cell reference from a numeric value in the 1st sheet. Now it is freezing on the memory.php page, line 82:"  // Return requested entry
  return $this->_cellCache[$pCoord];
 } // function getCacheData()"

It pulls a correct value in the preivous line, but freezes on this line. Thanks